# Why maximum probability (with bullets) at x=0 in double-slit experiment (Feynman's textbook)?

Tags: double-slit-experiment

In Feynman's quantum mechanics textbook, the first chapter deals with the [double-slit experiment.](http://www.feynmanlectures.caltech.edu/III_01.html). In the "classical part" regarding bullets, there is a sentence "You may wonder, however, why P12 has its maximum value at x=0." I don't understand the reasoning behind it, which follows after this sentence. After all, if we move the two holes further apart, there should be two maxima of the probability P12, whereby we can make P12 at x=0 arbitrarily small. So the statement in the textbook is wrong, isn't it?

A related question: [Double Slit Experiment/Transition of Classical to Quantum problems in Probability Addition in "An Experiment on bullets"](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/280790/double-slit-experiment-transition-of-classical-to-quantum-problems-in-probabilit)

Comment: You can wonder if the maximum is at 0. If reads in that case. Which is not a wonder anyway.

Comment: @Alchimista "If reads in that case. Which is not a wonder anyway." I am afraid I am not getting what you mean.

Comment: I assume that it should be taken as IF happens that. ...  in all cases is a bit obscure passage by Feynman or the curators as for being bullets what else should be? The wonders comes later in that lecture.

Comment: @Alchimista Well, even if it is obvious that it can happen, don't you think that it should be mentioned that P12 having its maximum value at x=0 is a special case which only holds if the distance between the two slits is small enough (as shown in https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/293269/63825)? Otherwise it is just wrong.

Comment: Yes is right. It is what I was saying. IF is a special case. I told you it is a bit obscure. I always read "You may wonder" as a possibility not an imperative; and " has its maximum value at x=0" as IF it happens to be.  An explanation as you suggest would have been clearer.

Answer (score 1):

I think the formulation in Feynman's textbook should be viewed as wrong, or at least misleading. Even though it is obvious that P12 can have its maximum value at x=0, it should be at least mentioned that this is a special case which only holds if the distance between the two slits is small enough, as shown [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/293269/63825)).